# Where are all the prospective Community Evangelist job applicants on SE?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, community, jobs

I applied to be a [Community Evangelist](http://stackexchange.theresumator.com/apply/5bbnOo/Community-Evangelism-Team.html) with Stack Exchange, and am curious why I'm not seeing any discussion of the job by other applicants.

Am I looking in the wrong place? Is this cheating? :) I would like to find out what other people experienced with the application, what else I could POSSIBLY do prove myself to the SE folks.

(Please let the answer be "Ask this question on SE!", and not "You Google badly, lady.")

Comment: Well, one reason you don't see *my* application is because it's based in New York! :) That aside, read Pekka's answer.

Comment: Do people usually talk about jobs they apply for?

Answer (score 13):

I don't have any inside information, nor experience with the application process, nor have I ever seen anybody here who has said to have actively applied for a job with SE, but this

> what else I could POSSIBLY do prove myself to the SE folks.

is pretty easy to answer: Become active on one or more of those of the sites on the network that genuinely interest you. Either as a contributor, or just as an observer in order to get familiar with the dynamics and rules of the community.

If you have time on your hands, digging through Meta's (this site's) archives to see how the sites have developed over the years might be an interesting idea - but be warned, it's a *huge* archive and contains a lot of noise.

I'm very sure having a thorough basic understanding of how these sites work can't be entirely wrong; a track record of some insightful contributions is probably going to be an even bigger plus. I don't know by what criteria they do their hiring, but they have always put a lot of emphasis on wanting to hire from within the community.

Comment: "I don't know by what criteria they do their hiring" -- Unicorn affinity helps. But no waffles, we have enough of that.

Comment: however, we never have enough bacon, so ... yea that helps

Comment: At LibraryThing, it was all about the brie. So, perhaps bacon-covered baked brie?

Comment: Are we sure we are not on the meta for cooking.SE?

Comment: @balpha HOW DARE YOU!